# Can I use templates to create a function that creates a variable without it appearing in function parameter list?

Tags: c++, templates

If I have function template like :

```
template<typename T>
void create()  // T absent here in function parameter list
{
   T var;  // variable of type T created without it appearing in function parameters
// do something
}
```

Is this a valid function? Can function use template variables without them appearing function parameter list?

Comment: Have you tried this yourself?  If you have, what issue did you see?

Comment: Yes, that's valid to do, and instantiations of these functions will be unique per template parameter signature. Did you try that and faced any problems so far? If so [edit] your question and elaborate please.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I haven't tried it yet but I am going to write a much larger and more complex function so even if it worked for a simple case like this I needed to make sure it is valid and I don't get any issues later on.

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma - `create` is a function that takes no arguments.  That is a perfectly valid C++ function.   Why would something like this: `void create() { int var; }` be any different?  You don't see the `int` in the parameter list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a valid function?

Yes it is a valid function template. But note that since there is **no way to deduce** the template parameter `T` from function call argument since the function takes no call arguments, you must **explicitly** specify the template argument when calling this function template as shown below:

```
int main(){
    create<int>();//pass int as template argument
    return 0;
}
```

Note that if you do not want to pass the template argument explicitly while calling the function template then you can use a **default template argument** which will be used in case you do not explicitly pass a template argument as shown below:

```
template<typename T = int>//default template argument
void create()  
{
   T var; 

}
int main(){
   create(); //NOW YOU CAN SKIP template argument
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Other than explicit argument stating, is there any other limitation on functions like these?

Comment: @PratapBiswakarma They behave the same as other function templates. Also, if you do not want to explicitly pass the template argument while calling the function template, then you can use **default template argument** as shown in my edited answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the code you wrote is valid, you call the function like:

```
int main(){
   create<int>();
}
```

Instead of `int` you can use any type of your interest obviously